# Unzip some Files in a Folder

Tags: python, permission-denied

I have a problem with unzipping some zip files in a folder. I know how to do it with one zip file, but I don't know how to do it with 3 or more files in a folder.

I've tried this:

```py
import zipfile
        
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Data/zipper/', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('C:/Data/unzipped')
```

But here, I get this error:

```
elf.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Data/unzipped/'
```

If I try this code with only one zip it works:

```py
import zipfile
    
with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("targetdir")
```

Comment: Evidently, you don't have permission to create / write to `C:/Data/unzipped`. Presumably that location requires elevated privileges. Try extracting somewhere else, or running your script with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Brian61354270 that’s my personal PC I’m a Admin there. I’ve tryed it also with an other location, but I get still the same error. Also with elevated privileges. 

If I try this with only one: import zipfile
withzipfile.ZipFile("file.zip","r") as zip_ref:
   zip_ref.extractall("targetdir") it works…

Comment: @INegativeI the thing is that your script, most probably, does not have the same rights as you (the user), so it may have some restricted privileges. Try to see the rights of your script and/or of the targeted folder with `ls -l` (if you're on linux) or `dir` (if you're on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to open the directory ('C:/Data/zipper/') as a zip file.

Try listing all the zip files in the directory and then looping through and unzipping them:

```
import zipfile
import os

# Directory containing zip files
zip_folder = 'C:/Data/zipper/'

# Directory to extract files to
extract_folder = 'C:/Data/unzipped/'

# List all files in the zip folder
files = os.listdir(zip_folder)

# Loop through all files and check if it's a zip file
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.zip'):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(zip_folder, file), 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(extract_folder)
```

Hope this helps.